# C++, Passing non-static function pointer in a class constructor

Tags: c++

I get the following compiler error when I used non-static function pointer in the constructor argument at myclass_2, void load (void) method.

> Reference to non-static member function must be called

If I change the function to static void load (void) no error. but I need to have non-static function, I have to work on some global variable in load function.
Any help would be appreciate it.

```
class myclass{
public:
    //_load_event_handler
    vector<Function> _handler_one;
    vector<Function> _handler_two;
    vector<Function> _handler_three;

    void register_for_load_event(void(*fun)(void)){
        this->_handler_three.push_back(fun);
    }

    void register_for_dowork_event(void(*fun)(void)){
        this->_handler_one.push_back(fun);
    }
    void register_for_end_event(void(*fun)(void)){
        this->_handler_two.push_back(fun);
    }
    void run (char **fileNames)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_one.size();i++)
            _handler_one[i]();


        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_two.size();i++)
            _handler_two[i]();


        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_three.size();i++)
            _handler_three[i]();
    }


};

class myclass_2
{
public:
    myclass *ptrmyclass;
    void load(void)
    {
        cout << "load function start" << endl;

        //some code here
    }
    myclass_2(myclass *_ptrmyclass)
    {
        ptrmyclass = _ptrmyclass;
        ptrmyclass->register_for_load_event(load);

    }
    void foo(vector<string> vect)
    {
        cout<< "is stop word called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: `void(*fun)(void)` is not a member function pointer, so it can only bind to free functions or static members. Try using `std::function<void()>` instead.

Comment: Can you please shrink your example so that we have a http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

Modifications:

1. I dont see what `Function` is in the question so I assume that to be `std::function<void()>`.
2. input of `register_for_load_event` should be a valid function object, so it needs a `bind`.

---

```
using namespace std;
class myclass{
public:
    //_load_event_handler
    typedef std::function<void()> Function; // -------- #1
    vector<Function> _handler_one;
    vector<Function> _handler_two;
    vector<Function> _handler_three;

    void register_for_load_event(Function fun){
        this->_handler_three.push_back(fun);
    }

    void register_for_dowork_event(Function fun){
        this->_handler_one.push_back(fun);
    }
    void register_for_end_event(Function fun){
        this->_handler_two.push_back(fun);
    }
    void run (char **fileNames)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_one.size();i++)
            _handler_one[i]();


        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_two.size();i++)
            _handler_two[i]();


        for (int i = 0; i< _handler_three.size();i++)
            _handler_three[i]();
    }


};

class myclass_2
{
public:
    myclass *ptrmyclass;
    void load(void)
    {
        cout << "load function start" << endl;

        //some code here
    }
    myclass_2(myclass *_ptrmyclass)
    {
        ptrmyclass = _ptrmyclass;
        ptrmyclass->register_for_load_event(bind(&myclass_2::load, this)); // -------- #2

    }
    void foo(vector<string> vect)
    {
        cout<< "is stop word called" << endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine but what happens if load would take some parameters like void load (char **filename). what should I change on "ptrmyclass->register_for_load_event(bind(&myclass_2::load, this));" thanks again for your great help

Comment: Ok, suppose it's now `myclass_2::load(char** filename)`; if you want to make a `std::function<void()>` object, then you need to `bind(&myclass2::load, this, filename)`; there are 2 parameters to `bind` since `myclass_2::load(char** filename)` is actually `myclass_2::load(myclass_2* ptr, char** filename)` when executing. Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind for more explanation. Keypoint: The purpose of `bind` is to make a function object which can be stored in `std::function`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `Function` is `std::function<void()>`, then change `register_for_load_event` to take a `Function` instead of what it takes now.  Finally, call it like this:

```
ptrmyclass->register_for_load_event(std::bind(&myclass_2::load, this));
```

`std::bind()` is needed because `Function` is nullary (takes no arguments), but `myclass_2::load()` requires one argument: the implicit `this` (because it is non-static, so requires an instance of `myclass_2`.  "Binding" the member function allows you to provide the `this` pointer at bind-time, but delay calling the function until later, when no arguments will be required.

Comment: You should explain why there is a need to use `std::bind`